# How to retrieve widgets from Single Layout ArrayAdapters

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a Listview full of rows, each with a textview and a spinner. I use an ArrayAdapter to fill in each row. There is a single layout for all the rows.

I want to have a button underneath all the rows that I can press so that it saves all the selections of the spinners in a Text file.

My problem though is I dont know how to reference the spinners anymore since I use the single layout approach. I no longer have unique IDs: (spinner1, spinner2, spinner3, etc.) for each one because they are filled in row by row.

Any advice on how to approach this problem so I can reference each spinner and call their "get text" method?

The more detail the better, thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a callback on the spinner for when an item is selected? You need to save this data somewhere against the position is it at. Perhaps a `Map<Integer, String>` and then you can use this to retrieve the information.

Comment: Is this the most elegant way to do it? Have a hashmap that is edited every time a new selection is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:  If the model object type of your array doesn't have a variable for the current spinner selection, you need to update your model or extend your Adapter so that you can capture the current selection of the spinner for that item.

In your adapter's `getView()`, when you create the spinner, add an `OnItemSelectedListener` to it that updates the model for its corresponding item in the array.

Then when the save button is pressed, you simply loop through the items in the adapter's array and get all the current spinner values.

Here is a code example:

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.spinnerdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String[] mValues = {
            "Strongly Agree",
            "Agree",
            "Neutral",
            "Disagree",
            "Strongly Disagree"
    };

    public static class MyModel {
        public String text;
        public int spinnerVal;
        public MyModel(String txt, int val) {
            text = txt; spinnerVal = val;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final List<MyModel> items = createItemList(); 

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // here is where we get all the spinner values
                Log.d(TAG, "------- save button clicked");
                for (MyModel model : items) {
                    Log.d(TAG, model.text + " : " + mValues[model.spinnerVal]);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "-------");
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<MyModel> objects) {
            super(context, 0, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            final MyModel model = (MyModel) getItem(position);

            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(model.text);

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(parent.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    android.R.id.text1, mValues));
            // here is where the spinner gets the value from the model
            spinner.setSelection(model.spinnerVal);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // here is where we update the model with the current position of the spinner
                    model.spinnerVal = position;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    private List<MyModel> createItemList() {
        List<MyModel> items = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
        // initialize with "Neutral" spinner setting
        items.add(new MyModel("question 1", 2));
        items.add(new MyModel("question 2", 2));
        items.add(new MyModel("question 3", 2));
        items.add(new MyModel("question 4", 2));
        items.add(new MyModel("question 5", 2));
        return items;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.spinnerdemo.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Save" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think I mostly understand your approach but not quite sure what you mean by "update your model to capture current selection". Could you give me a rough example of that, possible using high-level pseudo-code?